# Strange characters Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am new to Jquery mobile. When i try to insert radio buttons to my page i get  Â characters see example:

[image]

This is my code for the radio buttons:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
    <legend>Show in VK</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-c" checked="checked">
    <label for="radio-choice-c">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-d" >
    <label for="radio-choice-d">No</label>
</fieldset>
```

these are my includes ( nothing edited to the jquery mobile files )

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery.mobile.custom.structure.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery.mobile.custom.theme.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.mobile.custom.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Found the probleem.

When you use tab while programming it sometimes doesn't tab the way it should. (tabs become spaces)
Use right click -> page source and look for the characters. when you find them go to that line of code and delete all tabs there.

as you can see the A characters are gone:

[image]

Comment: This fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

You should add this at the top of your document

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

jQuery mobile uses spaces to clear out a few things but replaces `&nbsp;` with these weird characters without the meta being set.

Comment: How about the short HTML5 notation: <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: And what is in your lib/jquery.mobile.custom.js

Comment: 15452 lines of code directly downloaded from jquery mobile site 
i did NOT edit anything in there